# Commandline php curl not working?

Tags: php, curl, cmd

Hello i have php for commandline and trying to execute a curl link, but it don't works!

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init("https://albinstuff.net"); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

It outputs nothing, not even an error ...

I have enabled php_curl.dll extension ...

Comment: Add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);` before `curl_exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$url = 'http://yourUrl.com';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data); // use this for post fields
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

`curl` by default OUTPUTS whatever it finds, unless you turn on the "return transfer" option. As well, if curl fails, curl_exec will return a boolean false, which will print as an empty string.

Try:

```
$ch = curl_init(...);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false) {
    echo "Curl failed with error: ", curl_error($ch);
}
echo $result;
```